# Generate Numpad-Friendly Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, number-theory

*Inspired by [Generate Keyboard Friendly Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50047/generate-keyboard-friendly-numbers).*

### Background

Many number pads have the following layout:

<kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>

<kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

<kbd>0</kbd>

We define a number's neighborhood as the set of cells orthogonally adjacent to it on the numpad shown, including itself. For example, 2's neighborhood is `{1,5,3,0,2}` and 0's neighborhood is `{1,2,0}`. There is a list of each number's neighborhood below, above test cases.

We define a ***numpad friendly number*** as a positive integer where, when written in decimal without leading zeroes, each digit except for the first is in the neighborhood of the previous digit.

For example,

- 7856 is a numpad friendly number because 8 is in the neighborhood of 7, 5 is in the neighborhoood of 8, and 6 is in the neighborhood of 5.
- 1201 is a numpad friendly number because 2 is in the neighborhood of 1, 0 is in the neighborhood of 2, and 1 is in the neighborhood of 0.
- 82 is **not** a numpad friendly number because 2 is not in the neighborhood of 8.
- 802 is **not** a numpad friendly number because 0 is not in the neighborhood of 8 (neighborhoods don't wrap around).

[Related OEIS Sequence](https://oeis.org/A124097). Note that this related sequence is distinct because it counts <kbd>0</kbd> as adjacent to <kbd>7</kbd> instead of <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd>.

## Challenge

Given a positive integer `n`, return the `n`-th or the first `n` numpad friendly numbers, where the first is 1. You may use 0-based indexing, where the 0-th numpad friendly number would be 1.

## Neighborhoods

Each digits's neighborhood is listed here:

```
0:{0,1,2}
1:{0,1,2,4}
2:{0,1,2,3,5}
3:{2,3,6}
4:{1,4,5,7}
5:{2,4,5,6,8}
6:{3,5,6,9}
7:{4,7,8}
8:{5,7,8,9}
9:{6,8,9}
```

## Test Cases / Sequence

These are the first 100 terms

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 32, 33, 36, 41, 44, 45, 47, 52, 54, 55, 56, 58, 63, 65, 66, 69, 74, 77, 78, 85, 87, 88, 89, 96, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112, 114, 120, 121, 122, 123, 125, 141, 144, 145, 147, 200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 214, 220, 221, 222, 223, 225, 232, 233, 236, 252, 254, 255, 256, 258, 320, 321, 322, 323, 325, 332, 333, 336, 363, 365, 366, 369, 410, 411, 412, 414, 441, 444, 445, 447]
```

Comment: I like how this challenge [only considers positive integers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8437/36398) (which keeps the essence and allows more languages to participate) and allows displaying either the _n_-th or the first _n_ outputs for flexibility

Comment: I completely misread the challenge, here's an "is this term valid in the sequence" script: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVoApf8wNWFiMWX//8O84oCadnkxw6jigKIyzrNqeWTFks6Tw4rDq8OaxaDDi9GCVcO7dWrOteKAkzrOtOKAsC7Ok@KAomgnQcKhw61zw6h5MMOow6VYKlVY//80NDg "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>104</s> <s>93</s> <s>89</s> 88 bytes

Returns the N-th term of the sequence, 1-indexed.

```js
f=(i,k,n=k,N=n/5>>1)=>(N?8530025>>(n%10*6191^N%10*6191)%26&1:!i--)?N?f(i,k,N):k:f(i,-~k)
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(i,k,n=k,N=n/5>>1)=>(N?8530025>>(n%10*6191^N%10*6191)%26&1:!i--)?N?f(i,k,N):k:f(i,-~k)

for(n = 1; n <= 50; n++) {
  console.log('a(' + n + ') = ' + f(n))
}
```

Comment: Best I could get is 151 ```k=(n,a=1)=>n?k(n-([...(x=a+[]).slice(0,-1)].reduce((a,c)=>a*!!~"012 0124 01235 236 1457 24568 3569 478 5789 689".split` `[c].indexOf(x[i++]),i=1)),a+1):a-1``` maybe something there helps, my test is probably too long

Comment: This answer brings the concept of magic numbers to a whole new level... I don't even understand how you found them o_O

Comment: @scottinet To a large extent, my [explanation for this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143195/58563) applies to this one as well. The absolute difference didn't work very well on that one, so I tried with XOR instead. As a side note, I found another formula that worked in 96% of cases without the need for a lookup bitmask. But processing the remaining 4% separately was too costly in JS. I didn't try [in Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143694/58563), and now I don't remember the formula anyway... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. This is still impressive :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 123 + 1 (-p) = 124 bytes

```perl
while($_){$r=@d=++$\=~/./g;map$r&&=(120,1240,12350,236,1457,24568,3569,478,5789,689)[$d[$_-1]]=~/$d[$_]/,1..$#d;$r&&$_--}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzRCoIwFEA/poso3s3duc2JDPqBvsBEAqUEy2FBD2Kf3tJeDgcOHN/Pow7hfRvGPoY2WWB2x86lKZzdJ@PZtbpfPMxR5GKSAkmqHbkWKHODpHSBUmljMdemRFVY1IUt0dgyqaGroWXUNNvp702GxDkcumo/bo2t6xICCfGd/GuYHs/ATpoLEoH5Hw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

Returns the N first terms of the sequence.

```
D⁽ÞȦ×^2\%26“⁷wð’æ»ḂẠ
1Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//ROKBvcOeyKbDl14yXCUyNuKAnOKBt3fDsOKAmcOmwrvhuILhuqAKMcOHI///MTAw)

This is a port of [my JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143681/58563).

```
D⁽ÞȦ×^2\%26“⁷wð’æ»ḂẠ    - helper link: test numpad-friendliness of a number, e.g. 1257
D                       - get decimal digits             -> [1, 2, 5, 7]
    ×                   - multiply by ...
 ⁽ÞȦ                    - ... the integer 6191           -> [6191, 12382, 30955, 43337]
     ^2\                - bitwise XOR overlapping reduce -> [10353, 18613, 53666]
        %26             - modulo 26                      -> [5, 23, 2]
                æ»      - right-shift by each value ...
           “⁷wð’        - ... the integer 8530025        -> [266563, 1, 2132506]
                  Ḃ     - isolate the LSB                -> [1, 1, 0] which means that 1->2
                                                            and 2->5 are OK and 5->7 is not
                   Ạ    - all (0 if there's any 0)       -> 0, i.e. not numpad-friendly :'(

1Ç#                     - main link: return the [input] first matching numbers,
                          using our helper link as a monad and starting with 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
µNSü‚εW_iO<ë<3BÆ}ÄR2‹}P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f8wNWFiMWX//8K1TlPDvOKAms61V19pTzzDqzwzQsOGfcOEUjLigLl9UP//MTAw)

Returns the nth number in the sequence.

**Explanations:**

```
µNSü‚εW_iO<ë<3BÆ}ÄR2‹}P    Full program
µ                          Until counter is equal to input
 N                         Push current iteration number (e.g. 1025)
  S                        Split to a list of chars (-> ['1', '0', '2', '5'])
   ü‚                      Group into pairs (-> ['1', '0'], ['0', '2'], ['2', '5'])
     ε                     For each pair
      W_                      Is smallest digit equal to 0?
        iO<                      True: sum all digits and decrement 
           ë                     False: 
            <                       - decrement all digits
             3B                     - convert to base 3
               Æ                    - reduced substraction
                }             End if
                 Ä            Absolute value
                  R           Reverse 
                   2‹         1 if result is < 2, 0 otherwise
                     }     End for each
                      P    Cumulative product (1 if all pair results are 
                                     1, 0 otherwise)
                           -- implicit counter increment if stack value is 1
```

The main idea is that, apart from the `0` key, any digit decremented and converted to base 3 has the following properties:

- left and right neighbours have an absolute difference of 1
- up and down neighbours have an absolute difference of 10 which, reversed, is conveniently equal to 1
- any other pair of numpad keys result in different values, even when reversed

Of course we need a `if` statement to handle the `0` numpad key.

Comment: Solid answer, came to offer more improvements, can't find any. Oooo... and that pairwise put you in the lead too :).

Comment: I don't think I would've been able to come up with those 3 rules, pretty impressive tbh; what gave you the idea?

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 bytes

```
’d-,.⁸?3µ€ạ/S
Dṡ2Ç€<2Ạ
1Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8wUXR29R4077I0PbX3UtObhroX6wVwuD3cuNDrcDuTbGD3ctYDL8HC78v//hqYA)

-2 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing
-2 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

## Explanation

```
’d-,.⁸?3µ€ạ/S  Helper Link; compute the distance between two keys z = [x, y]
      ?        Switch:
     ⁸         If z (is not 0):
’              Decrement
 d             Divmod by:
  -,.          Else: [-1, 0.5] (special position for 0)
       3       3; right argument for divmod otherwise ignored
        µ      Begin a new monadic link / end this link
         €     Compute the position for each [x, y]
           /   Reduce on
          ạ    Absolute Difference
            S  Sum (this gives the Manhattan Distance)
Dṡ2Ç€<2Ạ       Helper Link; determine if a number <z> is numpad friendly
D              Convert number to decimal digits
 ṡ             Slice into overlapping slices of length
  2            2 (pairs)
    €          For each pair,
   Ç           The distance between the keys
     <2        Compare with 2 (the distance between two adjacent keys is 1; corners 2; 0 - 1 and 0 - 2 are 1.5)
       Ạ       All; either all of the distances are less than 2 or there were no distances
1Ç#            Main Link; find the first (input) numpad friendly numbers
  #            nfind; counting up from _ collect the first _______ matches that are
1                                      1
                                                           (input)
 Ç             Numpad Friendly
```

Comment: You can remove the `[]` for 2 bytes

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks!

Comment: [Golf a couple off.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8wUXR29R4077I0PbX3UtObhroX6wVwuD3cuNDrcDuTbGD3ctYDL8HC78v//hqYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
`@J3:qEt!J*+hYAd|2>~A?@]NG-
```

Outputs the first `n` numpad-friendly numbers.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HBy9iq0LVE0UtLOyPSMaXGyK7O0d4h1s9d9/9/QwMDAA)

#### Explanation

Each digit from `1` to `9` is encoded as a complex number representing its position in the numpad, using in a step-2 grid, where real part represents vertical position and imaginary part represents horizontal position. So `1` is `0+0j`, `2` is `0+2j`, `3` is `0+4j`, `4` is `2+0j`, ..., `9` is `4+4j`.

Digit `0` is encoded as `0+1j`, i.e. as if it were placed exactly between `1` and `2`.

For each candidate numpad-friendly number, a "decimal" base conversion is applied using the above complex numbers instead of the digits `0`, `1`, ..., `9`. This gives an array, of which the absolute consecutive differences are computed. The candidate number is numpad-friendly if and only if all absolute differences are at most `2` (i.e. the grid step). If that's the case, the number is left on the stack.

The code uses a `do`...`while` loop, which is exited when the amount of numbers in the stack equals the input `n`.

A unit grid would have been a more natural choice. Digits `1`, `2` and `0` would then correspond to `0+0j`, `1+0j` and `0.5+0j` respecrively. But it's golfier to use a step-2 grid, because multiplying by `2` (function `E`) and pushing `0+1j` (function `J`) is one byte shorter than pushing `0+0.5j` (`J2/` or `.5j`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 134 bytes

```python
g=lambda n,k=1:n and g(n-(lambda l:all(abs(a-b)<1.2for a,b in zip(l,l[1:])))([~-d%3+~-d/3*1j-d/~d*1.5for d in map(int,`k`)]),k+1)or~-k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBasMwDIbvfQpdBlLrZHXDLmF9klCoMmeeG0c2tnfoDnn1zIEKpB/E/33xWX6CXLbNXj0vo2EQNV91L8BiwKI0@Pr7nr1HHjNyM9Knbi/fIQGrEZzAn4volR90fyMiHNbGvHWnet@7o37UWM1Rtx87Yfb@whGdFHWf73QjNZ80hbQ28@aWGFKB/MyHum2eSpq@flN2QbxbXMHuXIcOMVUcB4uJYLem3ZpY7IRaQXeu1lfHoq4Abf8)

Comment: As you define `f` and then use it _once_, you could inline it and [save two bytes](https://tio.run/##LYzBasMwDIbvfQpdBlLrZHXDLmF9klCoMmeeG0c2tnfoDnn1zIEKpB/E/33xWX6CXLbNXj0vo2EQNV91L8BiwKI0@Pr7nr1HHjNyM9Knbi/fIQGrEZzAn4volR90fyMiHNbGvHWnet@7o37UWM1Rtx87Yfb@whGdFHWf73QjNZ80hbQ28@aWGFKB/MyHum2eSpq@flN2QbxbXMHuXIcOMVUcB4uJYLem3ZpY7IRaQXeu1lfHoq4Abf8).

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>249</s> <s>234</s> 202 bytes

```
(a=o=1;While[a<=#,s=IntegerDigits@o;t=1;p=0;While[t+p<Length@s,If[!FreeQ[(IntegerDigits/@{210,4210,53210,632,7541,86542,9653,874,9875,986})[[s[[t]]+1]],s[[t+1]]],t++,p++]];If[t==Length@s,a++];o++];o-1)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1NC4JAFEX/ShGEMi9y1PGDccBFBEKLWrUYZiEx6kCpOG8X/XYbI4I2h8vlXO6jxs7c7NyI2avFICi/duauZV2IDVhR9ahbPR1Ma9CWA0cnjCL4SkjG4qT7FrvSQtXI9XHS@iK9v9W@fIY0gHgBixYmUQgpiylkCYtDyBMWQZbGkGcpc0hevpRWSlSKUKVgiUtQgITASIhS3J2hEL/v2pV8@GBH/e18nkyPq7KRNAjU/AY)

*thanks user202729 for compressing data (-32 bytes)*

My results:

> 100 ->447
>   1000 ->20023
>   10000 ->788777

Comment: I think you can compress the data by using `IntegerDigits` : `IntegerDigits/@{210,4210,53210,632,7541,86542,9653,874,9875,986}`, and use `FreeQ`, `Tr`, use `Do` instead of `For`, use infix notation for `AppendTo` and use `Do` instead of `While` to repeat `Tr[1^s]` times, also eliminate the variable `p`. Also you haven't proven that the algorithm is correct, that is, the resulting number is always less than its index squared, which is necessary to make an answer valid.

Comment: @user202729 I changed a lot of things.My answer is definately valid. I'll compress the data now.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 124+1 bytes

```php
while($argn-=$r)for($p=$r=~0,$x=++$n;$x>=1;$p=[7,23,47,76,178,372,616,400,928,832][$c],$x/=10)$r&=!!($p&1<<$c=$x%10);echo$n;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/873fd8427780e2e1d16abf0a4f51cdd64086a0e4).

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>192</s> 190 bytes

```java
n->{int r=1,p;a:for(;n>0;){p=-1;for(int c:(r+++"").getBytes())if(p>-1&!"012;0124;01235;236;1457;24568;3568;478;5789;689".split(";")[c-=48].contains(p+""))continue a;else p=c;n--;}return~-r;}
```

Returns the (1-indexed) `n`'th number in the sequence.

This was surprisingly harder than I thought.. Probably just having some brain-farts this afternoon..

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##NVDBbsIwDL3vK7wcpkSlVQstFLxw2H1cOE4cshJQWJtGTcqEUPfrXVI2yX7Ws6VnvXcRVxG3RurL8WusamEtvAul708ASjvZnUQlYRfotICKBtQM/Wbw7WsHGvio4@09nDqezQyKzantKOptiuxueJxh4JPAhnZRFBHCkrN0bzcnLWVMnajZ8vTlmaTZHH3nARYFzhdLzPJihfO8WJa4CJCvSixW5RqX5Zok1tTKUYKEfVQxz8tDUrXaeQ@WmvCGBap0L0GgrK0EwyvUcYxDJ13f6Z@4w2HEhxfTf9aqAuuE8@PaqiM0XoruXaf0@eMAgj2yCCFBAxy0/J4InSIB@PepeIagXnmWpn5GEZuuAPubdbJJ2t4lxms62iQ68amyiMzIX6zD@As)

```java
n->{                 // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int r=1,           //  Return-integer
      p;             //  Previous digit
  a:for(;n>0;){      //  Loop (1) as long as the input is larger than 0
    p=-1;            //   Start `p` at an integer that is not 0-9 (-1 in this case)
    for(int c:(r+++"").getBytes())
                     //   Loop (2) over the digits of the current number
      if(p>=0        //    If this is not the first digit (`p` != -1),
         &!"012;0124;01235;236;1457;24568;3568;478;5789;689".split(";")[c-=48]
           .contains(p+""))
                     //    and the adjacent digits are NOT part of a NumberPad-Friendly Nr:
        continue a;  //     Go to the next iteration of loop (1)
      else           //    Else:
        p=c;         //     Set `p` to the current digit for the next iteration
                     //   End of loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
      n--;           //   If we haven't encountered the `continue`, decrease `n` by 1
  }                  //  End of loop (1)
  return~-r;         //  Return the result-integer - 1
}                    // End of method
```